# How to generate an embed code for a button

Tags: php, html, button, embed

I want to generate an embed code for a Donate button on my server so that anytime a user add the code to his/her website the Donate button will show

Comment: PayPal - Go to PayPal.  And no one clicks on Donate buttons.

Comment: This is not the place for these type of questions. Try help forums, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish this code on your website and ask web developers to insert this `<div>` into their web page html to let their visitor direct to your donation url. replace the link in code below with you donation url.

```
<div>
<button type="button"><a href="http://www.yourdonationurl.com">Make a Donation</button>
</div>
```